# Not the right subquery, multple counties in a state trying to get count of state

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SDRP15_COSD table
   | ST_code |      |SD Code|     |County Code|

     04                123            001
     06                232            001
     09                332            001


Submission table
| ST_code |         |SD_Code|         |Date|

     04                123            01/21/2003
     06                232            null
     09                332            01/21/2003
```

I tried it this way, but I don't think it fulfills my requirements.

```
select st_code, count(sd_code)
from sdrp15_cosd
where sd_code in 
(select sd_code from submission_table
where date is null)
group by st_code
order by st_code
```

The requirement here is the total count of each county listed in submission table for the corresponding state where the date field is null. Take into account that there are multiple counties in a state. and these tables are a simplified version compared to my 1000 rows.

Comment: Why a subquery rather than a join? Aside from that, why don't you think it fulfils the requirement - what result are you expecting, and what do you get?

Comment: It seems there are multiple states in a county, not viceversa.

Comment: @AlexPoole im suppose to be getting 3 character numeric, obviously I simplified the rows because having a 100 rows of data on here would be too overwhelming...and my co worker gave me a hint and told me to use a subquery. but idk where I would start if its a join condition.

Answer (score 0):

Think i got it. What you need to do is join the tables by both st code and sd code, and then simply use where date is null and group by county code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the desired results i am assuming few things 
   st_code and sd_code are unique for particular country.

```
select count(1),country 
from ex_9 a,ex_10 b 
where a.st_code = b.st_code 
and a.sd_code = b.sd_code 
and b.data is null 
group by country
```